# What do the symbols d/dx and dy/dx mean?

Tags: calculus, notation

Okay this may sound stupid but I need a little help... 
What do $\Large \frac{d}{dx}$ and $\Large \frac{dy}{dx}$ mean?

I need a thorough explanation. Thanks.

Comment: This is not precalculus, it is calculus. These symbols are derivatives. Are you familiar with derivatives?\

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The symbol
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}
$$
means the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$. If $y = f(x)$ is a function of $x$, then the symbol is defined as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.
$$
and this is is (again) called the derivative of $y$ or the derivative of $f$. Note that it again is a function of $x$ in this case. Note that we do not here define this as $dy$ *divided* by $dx$. On their own $dy$ and $dx$ don't have any meaning (here). We take $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a symbol on its own that can't be slit up into parts.

The symbol
$$
\frac{d}{dx}
$$
you can consider as an operator. You can apply this operator to a (differentiable) function. And you get a new function. So if $f$ is a (differentiable) function that it makes sense to "apply" $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $f$ and write
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f
$$
If you write $y = f(x)$, then this is the same as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}y = \frac{dy}{dx}.
$$

Comment: The confusion often arises from the fact that many writers call $dy/dx$ a "symbol" as if it were atomic, but then later start doing algebra with it.  This leads to the question, "well, then what is $dy$ really?"

Comment: @Fixee: That is right. I often see this confusion which is why I always emphasize that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is just a symbol. It is not a fraction.

Comment: @Thomas It's _kinda_ a fraction. It's the limit of a fraction.

Comment: (Or the "standard part" of a fraction, if you're doing nonstandard analysis...)

Comment: @Fixee See my answer. It is nevertheless CAN be defined as a fraction of two functions, rather than an atomic object.

Answer (score 7):

$\frac{d}{dx}$ means differentiate with respect to $x$.

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ means differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$.

Do you have any concrete examples for which you need to calculate these two? It would probably make it more easy to grasp for you if I could explain it in a few examples.

Comment: Maybe calculating the flow rate of a tap based on how the container gets filled?

Answer (score 3):

$d f$ means the *differential* of function $f$. By definition $(df)(x) = \lambda t\in\mathbb{R}:f'(x)\cdot t$. In other words, differential is the linear function (of an additional variable denoted $t$ here) whose tangent is the derivative of $f$.

$d$ alone means the differential operator (a function of argument $f$).

Exercise: Show that $\frac{df}{dx}=f'$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{F}{G}$ is defined for two functions $F$ and $G$ as $\frac{F}{G}(x)=\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$. Thus $\frac{df}{dx}$ makes sense.

Comment: It is described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

Answer (score 1):

I like to look at it this way: $dx$ and $dy$ are just representations of change in accordance to either $x$ or $y$ axis.
If you take the the symbol for derivative $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and compare it to the formula for the slope: $$\frac{f(x_1) - f(x_2)}{x_1 - x_2}$$ we can clearly see that $dy$ and $dx$ depict change in $y$ and change in $x$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=f(x)$ i.e., where $y$ is the equation ( the dependent variable) and $x$ is the independent variable. Meaning $x$ changes $y$.

Now $\frac{dy}{dx}$ means differentiate the equation $y$ in respect to $x$.

$\frac{d}{dx}$ means differentiate in respect to $x$.

Same way $\log x$ means find the natural logarithm of $x$, $\frac{d}{dx} x$  means find the derivative of $x$.

**N.B.** In an equation $k= h²+5 $, 
$\frac{dk}{dh}$ means differentiate the equation $k$ in respect to $h$. Its not always $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

I hope you understand

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See the answer given by Thomas