# Definition of a differential as $df(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

Take a function $f$ and a value $y$ at $x$ of $f$, the definition of a differential at $x$ is given by
$dy(x,dx)=f'(x)dx$ in general, why is the $dx$ variable then suppressed to give:

$dy(x)=f'(x)dx$? Do we just treat $dx$ as a parameter or is it so we can succinctly define the derivative function as the fraction of $dy$ and $dx$?

For example of this look at one of the answers/definitions in this question:

[What do the symbols d/dx and dy/dx mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340744/what-do-the-symbols-d-dx-and-dy-dx-mean)

Comment: Except in non standard analysis or in the calculus of differential forms (which you do not seem to have in mind) I am not aware of a rigorous definition of $dy$ or $dx$. Both notations $dy(x,dx)=f'(x)dx$ and $dy(x)=f'(x)dx$ are problematic. You seem to view $dy$ as a function of something that appears on the right hand side. Many people (most ?) find it acceptable to write $dy=f'dx$ since that is compatible with $\frac{dy}{dx}=f'$.

Comment: @KurtG, I have seen in some definitions the idea of $dx$ as a variable term, look at the update I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

The differential of a function $f:U\to V$ at a point $x\in U$, $df(x)$, is a linear map from tangent vectors $\delta x$ at $x$ to tangent vectors $df(x)\delta x$ at $f(x)$, and measures the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in the $\delta x$ direction.

For the case $U=V=\mathbb{R}$, you can write
$$\delta y = dy(x) \delta x = y'(x) \delta x$$
where $\delta x$ is a tangent vector at $x$, $\delta y$ is a tangent vector at $y(x)$, and both have been written as real numbers since you can canonically identify the tangent space at any point of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ itself (the sign of $\delta x$ gives you the direction of the tangent vector, and the magnitude of $\delta x$ is... the magnitude.) The differential $dy(x)$ in this case is simply scalar multiplication by $y'(x)$.

If you want you can go on to write $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x} = y'(x)$; there is no non-standard analysis here or any lack of rigor, just arithmetic of real numbers. But I'd avoid this notation since (1) it doesn't generalize when $U\neq \mathbb{R}$ and (2) it makes the "derivative is not a ratio!!!" people antsy.